# in data source view relationship between table is not showing

Tags: ssas, mdx

relationship between the data is not showing when I tried to used the data source view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pIfE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are relationships present. Plus even if they are not no problem, you can define them in the dsv. Simple create a logical primary key in you dimensions then drag the attribute from the fact to the dimension attribute.